# Knex JS - update & select in the same query (simultaneously)

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, knex.js

**Using Knex JS** - Is it possible to get all elements from the row being updated, I would like `update` and `select` to be done in a single query. (currently `update` only returns the `id` of the row being updated).

```
let query = await knex('items').select('id', 'customerId', 'itemId').where('id', id).update({ inactive: true })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Mysql does not support doing update and select in a single query. You have to do two queries inside a transaction to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If using `postgres`, then use `.returning()`

```js
const query: any = await knex('items')
  .returning('id', 'customerId', 'itemId')
  .where('id', id)
  .update({ inactive: true });
```

here is the knex documentation
https://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning